# How do you combine data from some columns but keep other separate?

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

In google sheet or excel i have date, product and qty of that product. One date has multiple columns of products and the associated qty. I want to combine the products columns and qty columns. Thanks for the help.

I've tried transpose(split(join function but can't get the date column to work. I've tried index match, but that only works with one column.

Now:
Columns with data are:

### Date  /  Product  /  Qty  /  Product  /  Qty  /  Product  /  Qty

### 1/1/2019  /  bananas  /  10  /  apples  /  5  /  oranges  /  2

### 1/2/2019  /  apples  /  5  /  oranges  /  3  /  bananas  /  20

I want:

### Date  /  Product  /  Qty

### 1/1/2019  /  bananas  /  10

### 1/1/2019  /  apples  /  5

### 1/1/2019  /  oranges  /  2

### 1/2/2019  /  apples  /  5

### 1/2/2019  /  oranges  /  3

### 1/2/2019  /  bananas  /  20

so I want to stack the data from the 3 columns of product and the 3 columns of qty but repeat the date for each combination

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets you could write a JavaScript function to iterate over your cells and create a new two-dimensional array according to your needs along the following lines:

```
var array = [['Date', 'Product', 'Qty', 'Product', 'Qty', 'Product', 'Qty'], ['1/1/2019', 'bananas', 10, 'apples', 5, 'oranges', 2], ['1/2/2019', 'apples', 5, 'oranges', 3, 'bananas', 20]]

var newArray = [];

for (var j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
for (var i = 1; i < array[0].length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 1) {
        newArray.push([array[j][0], array[j][i], array[j][i+1]]);
    }
}
};
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it works for you, I'd be thankful if you could mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this part actually. This data is getting added to everyday through the responses from a google form. So I need something that'll look at columns in one tab of a google sheet and then transpose it to list form in another tab. So instead of writing 'banana' in the script, I want it to be a column reference.

Comment: Hi, i found it in another spot, here's the formula if interested (assuming headers in row 1): =QUERY({{Sheet1!A2:A;Sheet1!A2:A;Sheet1!A2:A},{Sheet1!B2:C;Sheet1!D2:E;Sheet1!F2:G}},"Select * where Col2<>'' order by Col1")